# What is the criteria for rsyslogd to create symbolic link to my own file similar to /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

When I check the file descriptors opened by rsyslogd, i see the process have created symbolic link to /var/log/messages and similar files,

```
root@blr09> ll /proc/16635/fd
total 0
lr-x------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 1 -> /dev/null
l-wx------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 10 -> **/var/log/authlog**
lr-x------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 11 -> /run/log/journal/3da3ce2773004947b9a8d40578a1fb8b/system.journal
l-wx------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 3 -> socket:[4422054]
l-wx------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 4 -> **/var/log/messages**
lr-x------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 5 -> /run/log/journal/3da3ce2773004947b9a8d40578a1fb8b/system@3a558a8cce7b45a6bf810fe33c7a89d6-0000000000011e3c-0005453c395dc7aa.journal
lr-x------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 6 -> /run/log/journal/3da3ce2773004947b9a8d40578a1fb8b/system@3a558a8cce7b45a6bf810fe33c7a89d6-0000000000000001-00054520bb84848d.journal
lr-x------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 7 -> anon_inode:inotify
l-wx------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 8 -> **/var/log/secure**
l-wx------. 1 root root 64 Jan  4 08:29 9 -> **/var/log/cron**
root@blr09>
```

Below is rsyslog.conf

```
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*


# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###

auth.info       /var/log/authlog

*.*             @127.0.0.1:10514
```

My requirement is to create a similar file of /var/log/messages for some application messages so that rsyslog will send all the messages to port 10514 as configured in rsyslog.conf.

Could you please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: Do you want `rsyslogd` to send specific messages to a file or to a port on a remote `rsyslogd`?

Comment: As for the symbolic link, `rsyslogd` didn't create them nor was it aware of them. It's the kernel that created them when `rsyslogd` opened a file. `rsyslogd` is just aware of the file descriptors returned to it via the system calls.

Comment: @alvits, i need to send messages to a specific file and to a port on a local system.

Comment: @alvitis, is there any configuration to make aware rsyslogd to open my own file and filter out the messages to the file?

Comment: Yes you can make `rsyslogd` open your own file for certain messages. But sending the same message to local port 10514 where this `rsyslogd` is listening, will cause infinite loop. For example, you receive message 1, you write it to your file, then you forward it to local port 10514. You then receive this same message on port 10514 and write it to your file and send it to port 10514. You then receive this same message on port 10514...See what I mean?

Comment: @alvits, yes i got that. So, how to make rsyslogd open my own file for certain messages. This should be visible on file descriptors openend  by rsyslogd. I need this because my application is listening on rsyslog port and i want read all the messages sent to that port for some processing.